# Python facebookads sdk - can not find publisher_platform breakdowns

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to get the 'platform' (or sometimes 'publisher_platform') breakdown using the facebookads Python SDK, because we serve ads on Facebook and Instagram. Here's my code:

```
insights = account.get_insights(fields=[
    AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
    AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
    AdsInsights.Field.reach,
    AdsInsights.Field.spend,
], params={
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.ad,
    'breakdowns': AdsInsights.Breakdowns.publisher_platform,
    'time_range': {'since': str(datetime.date(2016,12,1)), 'until': str(datetime.date(2016,12,31))}
})
```

The code raised the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
AttributeError: class Breakdowns has no attribute 'publisher_platform'
```

Everything except line 8 is working. How to work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's actually missing from the SDK. You can just check in the file to see if it's there when you see this kind of issue.

Until it's available in the SDK, you can just use a string:

```
insights = account.get_insights(fields=[
    AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
    AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
    AdsInsights.Field.reach,
    AdsInsights.Field.spend,
], params={
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.ad,
    'breakdowns': 'publisher_platform',
    'time_range': {'since': str(datetime.date(2016,12,1)), 'until': str(datetime.date(2016,12,31))}
})
```